# How to print a colorful echo with $_SESSION['username']

Tags: php

I can not color the `$_SESSION['username']` while `echo` in php.

```
echo "Welcome, " .$_SESSION['username']."! "; //this code is running

echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Welcome,'$_SESSION['username'];'</span>'; // this part is not working...
```

Please help me if you can

Comment: A colorful echo? I don't understand your question. Use CSS to style your output. `echo '<span style="color: green;">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>'; `, is this what you want to do?

Comment: You forgot the `.` to concatenate the variable with the string. You did it right in the first line, left it out in the second line.

Comment: Thanks all... the problem is resolved now

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the concatenation `.`.

```
echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Welcome,' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</span>'; // this part is not working...
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the missing `.` before and after `$_SESSION['username'];`

```
echo'<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Welcome,'.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>';
```